# converting an image from rgb to cmyk using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rgb, cmyk

I use AngularJs to enable my users to upload an image file (jpg/png). I want to convert the uploaded image file to cmyk so that it can be used for printing purposes. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Are you looking to do this on the client-side using Javascript?

Comment: We need more information before we can help you. It sounds like you're uploading the file to some back end system, what language is that system using?

Comment: @alex Yes, I want to do it on client side.

Comment: @anierzad I am using NodeJs on the backend but I am not uploading the image on the backend. I am rendering the image on a template using fabric.js and then storing it on my s3 buckets.

Comment: If the image is on the client-side, why can't the client simply print the JPG or PNG image without performing any sort of conversion?

Comment: @alex well, that's the use case I have. Any idea how to do that though?